# What would be the syntax on these two functions as an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

Having trouble figuring out the syntax for arrow functions on these. I'm new to this...

```
var numbers = [1, 25, 6, 88, 47, 77, 333, 500];

var even = function (num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
};
var evens = numbers.filter(even);


var plusThree = numbers.map(function(element) {
  return element + 3;
});
```

Comment: What arrow functions? your question doesn't have any.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - the question is asking to "translate" regular functions to arrow notation, so, clearly there wouldn't be any arrow functions in the code given :p If the question had arrow functions, then the OP would know what an arrow function is :p

Comment: @JaromandaX you're right.

Comment: it's good to see such a poor quality question is answered so quickly though. Absolutely no effort made. (ಠ_ಠ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function (num) {
  return num % 2 === 0;
};
```

would become

```
(num) => num & 2 === 0
```

And

```
numbers.map(function(element) {
  return element + 3;
});
```

would become

```
numbers.map((element) => element + 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var even = num => num % 2 === 0;

var plusThree = numbers.map(element => element + 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

The most general recipe is that, given an anonymous function of this form

```
function(arg1,arg2,...) { code }
```

the corresponding arrow function is of this form

```
(arg1, arg2,...) => { code }
```

There is a special case where the `code` is nothing more than a return statement followed by an expression, i.e.  when you don't have any statement in the function code other than the return statement. In that case, you get something even nicer.

```
function (arg1,arg2,...) { return expression; }
```

becomes

```
(arg1,arg2,...) => expression
```

So in addition to what has already been posted, you could always do something like this (if, for example, you want your arrow function to have side effects)

```
numbers.filter(num => { console.log(num); return num % 2 == 0})
```

EDIT:
As pointer out in the comments, the `()` around the argument list is only necessary when you have multiple arguments. So the following also work

```
arg1 => { code }
arg1 => expression
```

Comment: how about the case with a single argument? `arg1 => ...`

Comment: `function(arg1){ code }` becomes `(arg1) => {code}` and `function(arg1) { return expression }` becomes `(arg1) => expression`.

Comment: or, the shorthand version WITHOUT `()` around `arg` is what I was getting at (ง︡'-'︠)ง

Comment: Oh my mistake, I hadn't even considered that case!